# Scene Turns purple on headset but not in editor

Tags: unity, graphics, oculus

I have a scene that looks fine in the editor and even if I am connected via Oculus link and am running the game the plane interior comes out fine. However when I push a build through adb or app lab I get this result :

[image: Purple Scene]

My first thought was maybe the lighting settings like maybe the light is not being baked in the scene properly. This doesn't look like the pink shader missing that Unity gives for missing shaders. Any idea where I should start looking/playing with ?

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps to create a minimal complete verifiable example of the problem, starting with a new, empty project? Once we can reproduce the issue, we can test potential fixes to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: I was able to find a fix though its probably not the best all I did was create a new scene and add a low poly skybox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up being able to solve the issue by taking off Realtime and mixed lighting options though it seems like being able to add baked lighting in there would be much faster than being overridden to Realtime lighting.

[image]